# Parse text Java regex match before whitespace, and numbers after whitespace to generate CSV

Tags: java, regex

At the moment I'm using this simple regex:

```
[^\s]
```

Which I cobbled together with the help of [these docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html).

It can grab the following information:

[image]

However the full dataset looks like this:

```
#### LOGS ####
CONSOLE:
makePush            2196
makePush            638
makePush            470
opAdd           8342
opAdd           288
opStop          133
0x
DEBUG:
#### TRACE ####
PUSH32          pc=00000000 gas=10000000000 cost=3

PUSH32          pc=00000033 gas=9999999997 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

PUSH32          pc=00000066 gas=9999999994 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
00000001  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

ADD             pc=00000099 gas=9999999991 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
00000001  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
00000002  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

ADD             pc=00000100 gas=9999999988 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
00000001  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

STOP            pc=00000101 gas=9999999985 cost=0
Stack:
00000000  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f
```

Finally I need my result to look like this:

```
makePush, 2196
makePush, 638
makePush, 470
opAdd, 8342
opAdd, 288
opStop, 133
```

And the `regex` I've provided is certainly not robust enough to capture that.

What I'm trying to do is:

- Ignore any string in the input that doesn't have the form `makePush            2196`
- For lines that are of the form depicted above...

  - Split it into three groups"

    `first word`, `whitespace`, `second word`
- Finally I want to save a csv of the form:

  `first word`,`second word`

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to match? Lets start by describing what makes *you* recognize that those are the values you want to match. For instance is it "whole line which with one or more alphabetic characters, followed by spaces, followed by digits? (and nothing else)"? In that case your regex can look like `\\w+\\s+\\d+` (possibly with groups so you could use only parts of that match).

Comment: I've added more context to the OP- describing what I'm exactly trying to do

Comment: So you are looking for something like `^([a-zA-Z]+)\\s+(\\d+)$`. Now in group 1 you have match from `[a-zA-Z]+` part and in group 2 match from `\\d+`. To get content of groups simply use `matcher.group(index)`.

Comment: I sort of did it with this `[a-zA-Z+[^ \t]+0-9]`, but is there a way to somehow- with java- ignore lines that *don't* have components that fit each one of those forms- you know what I mean?

Comment: You used `[....]` like it could match whole text, but this is *single* character set, so it can match single character from specified set at a time. You probably missed `]` before first `+` and `[` after second `+`. Also I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `[^ \t]`. `[^..]` is negated character set, so it will match everything except characters which are described there. There is also second meaning for `^`, if it is outside of `[...]` then it represents start of text, while `$` end of text. You can make it represent start/end of *line* with *multiline* flag.

Comment: Demo: https://ideone.com/SRF4XW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
/([a-zA-Z]+)[\t ]+(\d+)/g
```

where

- `([a-zA-Z]+)` matches a single word literals
- `[\t ]+` matches horizontal white spaces
- `(\d+)` matches the number literals

Answer (score 0):

Try this (idea from  Pshemo but use \w+)

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1)+", "+matcher.group(2));
        }
```

Comment: `\\w+` will also include `00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005` which doesn't look like result OP wants (that is why I used `[a-zA-Z]+` instead.

Comment: Also `^` and `$` by default match start and end of entire string, not lines. We need *multiline* flag to change that behaviour.